# Zoom breaks Scrollable Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that displays an interactive datatable with its Header and first two Columns (the buttons) fixed.

See it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/MULips).

The table consists of four parts (all having their own div)

1. Buttons Header (`div#buttonHeader`)

   - Fixed vertically and horizontally
2. Main Header (`div#mainHeader`)

   - Fixed vertically, Scrollable horizontally
3. Buttons Body (`div#buttonBody`)

   - Scrollable vertically, Fixed horizontally
4. Main Body (`div#mainBody`)

   - Scrollable vertically and horizontally

The problem is that zooming to different levels (110% on Chrome) on different browsers causes the body parts to render askew.

Is there a way to fix this without breaking the scrolling functionality?

Comment: Add the style `float:left` to your `#fullbody` element. This will mean that the body element is always aligned to the left. _this will work but is probably not best practice_

Comment: @ThomasDevries I tried this but, unfortunately, it breaks my horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a chance to look at your code at a meetup. Found that `#buttonheader` was floating but `#mainBody` was unable to clear it due to a height being explicitly set.

Once we removed the height, page flow worked as expected. My hunch was that the height of 59px was being scaled to 110% or 64.9px which was then rounded and conflicting with the border box of `#mainBody` somehow.

Moral was... keep turning off styles in DevTools until you find the conflict, then find a different way to do what it was solving.